# How to use <xmlpeek> in NAnt

Tags: nant

Can anyone suggest me with examples the way to use this  command in the nant.build folder.If suppose i have an build.log file and i wann search errors or any particular pattern.

I had tried that link of nant but just unable to figuer out correctly the way we should use those ones.

Thanks and regards 
Maddy

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
<exec program="svn" output="${project-root}\svninfo.xml">
  <arg line="info --xml"/>
</exec>

<xmlpeek file="${project-root}\svninfo.xml"
         property="subversion-revision-number"
         xpath="/info/entry/@revision" />

<delete file="${project-root}\svninfo.xml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here for description and examples:

http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/xmlpeek.html